# Peace of parents vs Gaming

Tags: korean-culture

When I watch youtube videos related to games, I encounter several
comments where people **relate the peace of parents to the reason** that
Koreans are good at gaming.

> " 한국에서는 게임 못하면 부모님 안부를 물어 보거든 (1) "
>
> In Korea, if someone is not good at game, then we ask him a peace of
>   parents.
>
> 부모님을 지키기 위해 (2) To protect parents
>
> 부모님께 효도 (3) obedience to parents.

Even though I do not do game, I can understand other
reasons. But what does (1) (2) (3) mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Korean expressions which mean that the opponents' parents passed away. For example, you can ask a question, "Are your parents well?" It seems that the sentence is very normal, but the intention of the phrase is to say that the listener's parents are not well. These are used in chats very frequently.

What (2) means is to prevent such expression, being good at games are necessary. `효도` is not just obedience, it is more likely to be "do not do mean things to parents". So the context is the same to (2).